# Excel Match Multiple Criteria with Match Type = 1 Breaks with Large Dataset

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I would like to search data for the existence of a number (e.g. 1430), given that two criteria (dates) are already met.  If that number doesn't exist, I would like to return the largest value, for those two criteria, that is less than my target number.

I am using the following method:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482

Additionally, I am leaning on the help files for MATCH via Excel's help system, outlining MATCH_TYPE:

```
1 or omitted: MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order, for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE.
```

As such, I have sorted my data such that the two date series are ordered from oldest to newest and the target values are ordered smallest to largest.

This:

```
{=INDEX(data!$C$2:$C$21, MATCH(a2&b2&c2,data!$A$2:$A$21&data!$B$2:$B$21&data!$C$2:$C$21,1))}
```

(where a2 = 2/16/01, b2 = 3/17/01, and c2 = 1430)

works fine on my small test set, returning 1425, as expected:

```
Trade   Maturity    Strike
15-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   600.00
15-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   625.00
15-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   650.00
16-Feb-01   16-Mar-01   1300.00
16-Feb-01   16-Mar-01   1325.00
16-Feb-01   16-Mar-01   1375.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1400.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1410.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1425.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1450.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1475.00
16-Feb-01   17-Mar-01   1500.00
16-Feb-01   18-Mar-01   600.00
16-Feb-01   18-Mar-01   625.00
16-Feb-01   18-Mar-01   650.00
16-Feb-01   18-Mar-01   675.00
13-Mar-01   21-Apr-01   600.00
13-Mar-01   21-Apr-01   625.00
13-Mar-01   21-Apr-01   650.00
13-Mar-01   21-Apr-01   675.00
```

But fails on my actual test set with over 82,000 rows of data.  Concretely, when I run the search on the full data set, it returns the largest value for the last date prior to the target trade date (e.g. 650).

I've searched for hours and let it marinate in my head for a few days but cannot seem to crack this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you concatenate 3 numbers together (dates are numbers) "600" is greater than "1500", that's why it fails, see my solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(F1;IF((A2:A21=G1)*(B2:B21=H1);C2:C21;"");1;1)
```

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

F1 contains, in this case the strike to look for, G1 and H1 Trade and Maturity

Comment: This works.  Thank you!!!!!!  Two questions: 1) Do you have any idea why the index-match method fails?; and, 2) Is the if statement in your formula creating a new array?

Comment: Also, how may I be certain that it pulls the greatest value less than my target?

Comment: Its not index+match that fails, its the concatenation, numbers will became text and, in text, "600" is greater than "1500". As long strike is sorted for each Trade, Maturity combination it will work.

Comment: 2) Yes an array with empty text for no matching Trade, Maturity combination and containing the strike value for the match Trade, Maturity combination